# Is there a shorthand for $watching a boolean expression to become true in controller

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Sometimes I end up `$watch`ing for a boolean expression to become true in controller (to do a redirect or some other magic that belongs to a controller).

*(typescript)*

```
$scope.$watch('aComplexBoolean && expressionWith && lotsAstuff', (newValue) => {
    if (newValue) {
        // do my stuff, e.g. redirect etc..
    }
});
```

I was wondering, is there possibly a shorthand in AngularJS for this, I would really like to get rid of the extra clutter and just call for example `$when('expr', () => { /* do stuff */ })` or something else equally nice and to the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such shorthand, as shown by the [`$rootScope` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope). But you can create it yourself by modifying the `$rootScope` object:

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

myApp.run([
    '$rootScope',
    function ($rootScope)
    {
        $rootScope.$watchTrue = function (expression, callback)
        {
            // Here, `this` refers to the scope which called the function
            return this.$watch(
                expression,
                function (newValue, oldValue)
                {
                    if (newValue) {                
                        callback(newValue, oldValue);
                    }
                }
            );
        };
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

No. But I prefer to use an early exit instead of wrapping in an if:

```
$scope.$watch('aComplexBoolean && expressionWith && lotsAstuff', (newValue) => {
    if (!newValue) return;

    // do my stuff, e.g. redirect etc..
});
```

It is also not uncommon to have multiple early exits and this pattern is much better than wrapping in an `if`.

Comment: Agree, definitely martin / clean code stuff and I'm fan of early exits my self (code marches less to the right)